# Remove period and text after in list

Tags: r

I have a list

```
t <- list('mcd.norm_1','mcc.norm_1', 'mcr.norm_1')
```

How can i convert the list to remove the period and everything after so the list is just

```
'mcd' 'mcc' 'mcr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(stringr)

lapply(t, function(x) str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

t <- list('mcd.norm_1','mcc.norm_1', 'mcr.norm_1')

t %>% 
  str_remove("\\..*")

#> [1] "mcd" "mcc" "mcr"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another option:

```
unlist(sapply(t, \(x) regmatches(x, regexec(".*(?=\\.)", x, perl = TRUE))))

[1] "mcd" "mcc" "mcr"
```